# Every animal in the zoo is fed regularly and (is?) attended to very promptly

Tags: exam-questions

> Every animal in the zoo is fed regularly and  attended to very promptly.

Considering formal English usage for exam purpose, Is it okay to do away with second **is** after *and* in the above sentence or Do I need to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here I suggest you the answer:

***Every animal in the zoo is fed regularly and attended to very promptly.***

Explanation:
There is no need to use a helping verb before "attended" since we already used it earlier.

The use of the preposition 'to' after attended is correct, since this is the phrasal verb "to attend to (something)"
.